# Accessing raw partition in Android using Java

Tags: java, android

I have a partition in Android that's not mounted because it doesn't have a file system, and I need to write a string into it.  I tried three different methods, and only the first (from adb) works.  I need to do this under program control, which is what the second and third methods do, but both fail.  I tried adding system permissions to my app, but that didn't help.  Do I need root permission to do this from a program?

**First Method -**

```
adb shell "echo test > /cache/command"
adb shell dd if=/cache/command of=/dev/block/mmcblk3p3 bs=4096 seek=1
```

**Second Method -**

```
java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
"dd if=/cache/command of=/dev/block/mmcblk3p3 bs=4096 seek=1");
```

**Third Method -**

```
File fileName = new File("/dev/block/mmcblk3p3");
String cmd = "test";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
fos.write(cmd.getBytes(), 4096, cmd.length());
fos.flush();
```

The second method gives no feedback, even though it failed to work.  The third method gives the following output:

```
W/System.err( 1014): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/dev/block/mmcblk3p3 (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Why do you want to write to a partition that does not have a file system?

Comment: Give the right permissions to /dev/block/mmcblk3p3

Comment: @Hemal: This partition is used to communicate between Android and bootloader, so it doesn't have a file system.

Comment: @dtmilano: I tried chmod 0666 on the partition using adb, but it resets itself to 0600 on reboot.  Is there any way to give it rw access to non-root users permanently?

Comment: I solve these problems (i.e. programmatic reboot) by creating a utility app (no UI used) and compiling it as a system file and putting it (with 'cat') into "/system/app". That way it'll run with elevated permission without needing to chmod 666 in init.rc. Your main app can then use your utility app via intents - so your main app will be indirectly able to perform system-level API's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should warn you about the risks you may have enabling liberal permissions on partitions that should not be accessed by applications. Having said that and assuming you know the risks, what you can do is to change the permissions, if you want to do it permanently you can add

```
chmod 0666 /dev/block/mmcblk3p3
```

to `init.rc`.
There are sections containing other chmod commands where you can put yours.